# Extract Method not running on VStudio2022

Tags: visual-studio-2022, extract-method

do you have any idea why the extrac method is not working on VStudio2022.

Example:
be selecting following code, and if I go to EDIT->Refractor->Extract Method error appears like in the screenshoot.

[No valid selection to perform extaction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7Ql9.png)

```
var stack = new SimpleStack();
stack.Push(1.2);
stack.Push(2.8);
stack.Push(3.0);

double sum = 0.0;

while(stack.Count > 0)
{
    double item = stack.Pop();
    Console.WriteLine($"Item: {item}");
    sum += item;
}

Console.WriteLine($"Sum: {sum}");

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Does it do this in other classes, or only in the new stripped-down Program.cs?

Comment: Hi, I managed to highlight a small section of code and extracted it using edit >refactor >extract to method on a MainPage.xaml.cs (Maui), but I can't understand why this isn't on right click of highlighted code. (I'm fairly new to visual studio 2022)